# Como criar um objeto DateTime que represente o último dia de um determinado mês?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Em um objeto do tipo `DateTime`, como faço pra obter um objeto novo objeto `DateTime` que represente o último dia do mês do primeiro objeto?

```
var data = new Date(2017, 3, 1); // 01/03/2017
var dataUltimoDia = ??? // 31/03/2017
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote [FluentDateTime](https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime). Ele disponibiliza o método de extensão `LastDayOfMonth()` além de uma porção de outras extensões extremamente úteis.

Você pode instalá-lo pelo nuget

> PM> install-package [FluentDateTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentDateTime/)

Uso

```
using FluentDateTime;
...
DateTime ultimoDiaDoMes = qualquerData.LastDayOfMonth();
```

E também pode fazer de uma maneira (que eu julgo) mais simples do que esta na sua resposta

```
var qualquerData = new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, 1);
DateTime ultimoDiaDoMes = qualquerData.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Ótimo pacote esse. No meu caso agora não posso utilizar pacotes de terceiros, mas vou lembrar dele em meus projetos.

Answer (score 10):

[Encontrei essa resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078954/how-do-you-find-the-last-day-of-the-month#answer-4078990)

Para obter apenas o dia existe o método [DaysInMonth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) que recebe como parâmetros o mês e o ano e irá retornar um `int` que será o último dia.

Com o último dia recuperado, criei um novo objeto do tipo `DateTime` utilizando o mês e ano do meu objeto original mais o dia recuperado.

```
var data = new DateTime(2015, 11, 7);
var ultimoDia = DateTime.DaysInMonth(data.Year, data.Month);
var dataUltimoDia = new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, ultimoDia);
```

Comment: Podem até falar mal da linguagem php, mas nele essa operação seria feita em apenas uma linha ;)

Comment: Eu consigo fazer em uma linha @WallaceMaxters :P

Comment: @WallaceMaxters faz tempo que não brinco com PHP, mas PHP não tem linq até onde eu saiba, e linq é tudo! :)

Comment: `DateTime ultimoDiaDoMes = qualquerData.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);` @WallaceMaxters :P

Comment: @jbueno assim irá funcionar apenas se `qualquerData` for o primeiro dia do mês. xD

Comment: Lol verdade @PedroCamaraJunior. Duas linhas então :P

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior se link for o que chamamos de `chainability` então podemos fazer sim no php `(new DateTime('last day of mouth'))->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format()`

Answer (score 5):

> como faço pra descobrir o último dia desse mês?

```
var ultimoDia = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
```